# Assign string into multidimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assumed that I have below string

```
[["Fri, 28 Mar 2014 01:00:00 +0000",0.402053266764,"1 sold"],["Thu, 03 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000",6.5,"1 sold"]];
```

How can i assign this set of string into an array?

Expected result:

```
string[,] items = {
{ "Fri, 28 Mar 2014 01:00:00 +0000", "0.402053266764", "1 sold"},
{ "Thu, 03 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000", "6.5", "1 sold"}
                  }
```

Comment: You must parse your string and gather required data.

Comment: split by `,` and then replace `[` and `]`

Comment: Where is this set of string stored?

Comment: @Rahul that won't work as his lines contain "," also inside the single parts

Comment: Rahul, it WILL split but it won't split in the way the user wants to. As example, the line showed in his post it will be split not in 2 parts but in 7.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano, yep .. didn't see that. removed my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute force attack, probably better solutions are available

```
string input ="[[\"Fri, 28 Mar 2014 01:00:00 +0000\",0.402053266764,\"1 sold\"],[\"Thu, 03 Apr 2014 01:00:00 +0000\",6.5,\"1 sold\"]]"; 
string temp = input.Replace("[", "");
string[] records = temp.Split(new char[] {']'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[,] output = new string[records.Length, 3];
int recno = 0;
foreach(string record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record);
    string[] fields = record.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    output[recno,0] = string.Join(",", fields[0], fields[1]);    
    output[recno,1] = fields[2];    
    output[recno,2] = fields[3];    
    recno++;
}

for(int x = 0; x <= output.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y <= output.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
        Console.Write("INDEX[" +x + "," + y +"]=" + output[x, y] + ";");
    Console.WriteLine();                            
}
```

Comment: What if i split by `,[` and then just replace rest of the `[` and `]`? what you say!

Comment: Yes possible but then you should remove the double square brackets at the start and at the end of the inputs, not a big gain. For Example this single line could replace the first two  `var temp = input.Split(new string[] {",["}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim(new char[] {'[', ']'}));`

Comment: Correct agreed. I always get confused with LINQ (trying to learn it currently). Can you suggest a easy/efficient way to master LINQ/LAMDA expression. Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul I am like you, I don't master enough LINQ to be confortable  to give advices. However, there is this powerful tool called [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) that will let you try and test your ideas without the big and hefty Visual Studio. This is all that I can suggest.

Comment: A suggestion is a `suggestion`; no matter small or big. Thank You Steve. Have a nice weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputString; //Your original string
inputString=inputString.Replace('[',' '); //Removes left bracket
inputString=inputString.Substring(0,inputString.Count()-2); //Removes last two right brakets
var arrayOfStrings=inputString.Split(']'); //Split on right bracket
for(int i=1; i < arrayOfStrings.Count() -1; i++){
    arrayOfStrings[i]=arrayOfStrings[i].Substring(1); //Removes the "," at the start of the 2nd to the n-1th elements
}
```